# For check variable, which condition will given?

Tags: c#

I have two textboxes. One for a clock in time and one for clock out. The times will be put in this format:

```
Hours:Minutes
```

Let's say I have clocked in at 22:00 AM and clocked out at 2:00 PM.

How would I do that in C#.

So, basically, how would I give condition for check clocked in at 22:00 AM?
I want get error here.if user give clocked in time at 22:00 AM.

```
string starttime = "22:00 AM"; 
string endtime =2:00 PM;

DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(starttime); //get error:(String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)<br>
DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(endtime);
```

Comment: i trying to achieve which condition i will give to if user enter "22:00 AM" and get error like ex: its not valid.

Answer (score 2):

What I am gathering from this is that you want to throw an error when you have something out of the limit of 01:00 to 24:00 or 01:00AM to 12:00PM he first thing that I would do is decide on what format you want to use. Then depending on what project you are working on, if its a winform I would use a Masked editor and set it to the format that you want (0:00AM/PM or 00:00) and add an errorProvider, if it is a WPF project you will have to do something like the code below;

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Time,StringFormat=hh\\:mm}"/>
```

Hope this helps:)